# How can I test something that changes?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm looking to test a script that, given some parameters, replicates data from our API to a location on our CDN.

However, this constantly changes. How should I add a test for it? Perhaps add something to the API that always returns the same thing when given some parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are touching one of the very important aspect of unit-testing: it forces you to write "good" code. If you want your code to be successfully testable in the kind of cases you're describing, you *have* to use good practices like [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concern).

In other words, to write successful tests, you *need* to abstract out your dependencies, preferably to interfaces. You can then run your tests by injecting a [stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub) or a [mocked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) implementation of that interface, which has reproducible and controllable output. By doing this, you're testing only the logic (behaviour or state, depending on tastes) of your unit under test, and not your dependencies. It forces separation of concerns on you.

(I would give examples but you didn't specify which language you're using)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to be a smartass but, if you have no defined expectation, you have nothing to assert in the test.

Test everything that should be there. If you don't care about some part of the output, just test it's existence. If there should be a correlation of some things inside the output, test that.

Comment: No worries. And that definitely makes sense—thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have a start on your answer.  To test your script, you need a test framework that allows you to feed a known input state to the script, capture the output, and check the output for correctness.

It's not clear what the referent of "this" (constantly changing) is.  The location on the CDN? If so, you'll need to freeze that location for testing.